# Import multiple data on one cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, flatten

Hi I have data on columns A, B, C, D on Google sheet

I added the following formula on H2 which works in importing columns C & D as wished.:

```
 =UNIQUE(filter(C2:D,A2:A<>""))
```

I tried inserting this formula in J2 but it doesn't handle duplicates:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(H2:H=C2:C,B2:B))
```

My goal is to get the results written manually in G columns on this snip and keep the previous formulas. It should write the name of door twice if necessary separated by a comma or write the different doors in the same cell adjacent to the name.

Please help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 QUERY({A2:A&",", B2:B&"×", ROW(B2:B)}, 
 "select max(Col1) where Col1 <> ',' group by Col3 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), ",$", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with the formula below

```
=join(", ",filter($A$2:$A, $B$2:$B=D2))
```

Unfortunately, this formula is not an arrayformula, and I am not completely certain how to turn it into one (if there is a way). Because of that, this formula will need to be dragged down the column you place it in.

Here is an example of it working in the test sheet I made:

[image: ex]

I will continue to try to make this usable with an array formula, and will edit this answer if I am able to find a solution.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yeah that works, but I am trying to make it automatic as the result are uploaded into a dashboard, so I would love it to be an arrayformula